# Specify memory for ant maven deploy task

Tags: deployment, maven, ant

I am using ant maven deploy task to upload the zip file created by the ant script to our repository, but the problem is the file is too big and it fails with 
***java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space***. Following is the task

```
    <deploy uniqueversion="false">
      <remoterepository url="${repository}" id="${repositoryId}"/>
      <remotesnapshotrepository url="${snapshotRepository}" id="${snapshotRepositoryId}"/>
  <attach file="target/${qname}-dist.zip" type="zip"/>
  <pom file="pom.xml" groupid="com.my.company" artifactid="test" packaging="zip" version="${version}" />

</deploy>
```

How do I specify memory heap size here, I don't seem to find anything in deploy task or some of its children task.

Answer (score 1):

Maven doesn't fork on the deploy task so to increase the memory, you have to increase the heap size for the maven executable itself. You can just set your MAVEN_OPTS environment variable to include the -Xmx setting:  `MAVEN_OPTS=”-Xmx512m”`

Comment: This won't work, as we want to give it to the deployment team to run it and they would run it from multiple pcs, we don't expect them to set the environment variables to run it.

Comment: Why not just write a simple script that wraps your maven call? You can set and export the MAVEN_OPTS argument and then call mvn deploy. Then give that script to your operations team.